# How to make the same thickness in several places?

Tags: modeling

How to make the same thickness of the roof in several places? I don't want to change angles of edges to 90 degrees to measure it, I wanna keep edges with existing angles. Help me, please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to extrude with the *Shrink/Fatten* mode: Select your mesh, press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, choose the *Along Normals* mode, drag the extrusion, then in the last operation box (bottom left) enable *Offset Even*.

(You could also use a *Solidify* modifier, in this case, enable its *Even Thickness* option)

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand how that can help me. Maybe I do something wrong? Here are the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YlVx.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtmRZ.png

Comment: so maybe give a bit more informations about what your object looks like, what you want to do etc...

Comment: I just want to get the roof of my car the same width, but I don’t want to change the angles of the vertical edges. Is it possible?

Comment: You could extrude on the z axis: E then Z?

Comment: I don't want to have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdOGr.png, I wanna have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz0ky.png with the same width from begin of roof to its end.

Comment: What's the difference between your 2 pictures?

Comment: The difference is that in the first picture the roof consists of the vertical edges with angles of 90 degrees, and I want the roof to consist of vertical edges with different angles like in the second picture, but at the same time have the same width anywhere.

Comment: Ok understood, i don't think there's any direct method for this

Comment: I solved my problem: I used a Solidify modifier(I only now realized how to use it to make what I wanted), as you advised me. Thank you. Write me, please: how to delete questions on Blender Stack Exchange=)